# pip install pyqt5 taking to long. Why is it compiling? Is there no precompiled binaries for raspberrypi?

Tags: pi-4

Running

```
python3 -m pip install pyqt5
```

on a Raspberry Pi 4 is taking to long to compile... Why is it compiling anything? Is there no binary distribution of pyqt5?

If there are no pre-compiled distributions of pyqt5 where might I get started in packaging it myself?

Might it be possible to compile on one device and then grab the compiled binaries from somewhere and package them into a wheel?

*Note*:
Compiling on each device is not really an option. We have several dozen Raspberry Pis to deploy to that cannot afford the downtime.
This application also happens to be cross platform so I would like to depend on setuptools/pip to resolve the pyqt5 dependency rather than relying the linux distro's package manager.  (i.e. `apt` ...)

Comment: Try `apt-cache search pyqt5` - indeed ALWAYS search for existing code FIRST.

Comment: It's also worth checking on https://www.piwheels.org to see if they have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python3-pyqt5 available in the repository for Bullseye and Bookworm.

It may already exist; my apt shows `python3-pyqt5/stable,now 5.15.9+dfsg-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]`

You should ALWAYS check apt before trying pip (which takes ages) and indeed under Bookworm requires installing into a venv.

"This application also happens to be cross platform so I would like to depend on setuptools/pip to resolve the pyqt5". If there is a precompiled wheel pip should install this - although from python 3.11  this probably wouldn't apply.